# delegate not working on Ajax loaded content

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a situation where the anchor tag with the class `confirm_booking` is generated by Ajax. So I used `delegate`.

The div containing this anchor is now also generated by Ajax.
After loading the div via Ajax this function fails.

```
$('.restro_book_div').delegate('a.confirm_booking', 'click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('ul.time a').removeClass('clicked_confirmed');
    $(this).addClass('clicked_confirmed');
    var $current = $(this);
    var $reserve_restaurant_id = $current.attr('reserve_restaurant_id');
    var $reserve_time = $current.attr('reserve_time');
    var $table_type_id = $current.attr('table_type_id');
    var $reserve_date = $current.attr('reserve_date');
    var $reserve_slot = $current.attr('reserve_slot');
    var $reserve_discount = $current.attr('reserve_discount');
    var $reserve_loyalty_points = $current.attr('reserve_loyalty_points');
    var $reserve_table_type = $current.attr('reserve_table_type');
    //          alert(document.getElementById('standard-dropdown').value);
    //          console.log($current);
    //          console.log($reserve_loyalty_points);
    var $jquery_time = $current.attr('jquery_time');
    var $restro = $current.attr('restro');
    $target = $current;
    var popID = $target.attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
    var popURL = $target.attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size
    <?
    php
    if (is_user_logged_in()) { ?>

        $('#' + popID + ' .popup_heading').html('<span>THIS BOOKING IS VALID FOR</span> ' + $reserve_table_type + ' <span>PEOPLE AT</span> ' + $restro + '<br/> <span>ON</span> ' + $reserve_date + ' <span>AT</span> ' + $jquery_time); <? php
    } ?>

    //Pull Query & Variables from href URL
    var query = popURL.split('?');
    var dim = query[1].split('&');
    var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //Gets the first query string value

    //Fade in the Popup and add close button
    $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({
        'width': Number(popWidth)
    }).prepend('<a style = "display:inline;" href="#" class="close"><img src="<?php echo DIVATEMPLATEPATH."/".IMAGEPATH ?>/close.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>');

    //Define margin for center alignment (vertical   horizontal) - we add 80px to the height/width to accomodate for the padding  and border width defined in the css
    var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 80) / 2;
    var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;

    //Apply Margin to Popup
    $('#' + popID).css({
        'margin-top': -popMargTop,
            'margin-left': -popMargLeft
    });

    //Fade in Background
    $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); //Add the fade layer to bottom of the body tag.
    $('#fade').css({
        'filter': 'alpha(opacity=80)'
    }).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer - .css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}) is used to fix the IE Bug on fading transparencies 

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Then you'll need to target the next parent that isn't dynamic, or the document if there is no such parent :

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.confirm_booking', function(event){
    // do stuff
});
```

and on() would be the preferred method in newer versions of jQuery !

Comment: If this does'nt work, you either have no anchor element with the class confirm_booking, or you're using an old version of jQuery ?

Comment: this thing is working when the parent div of anchor tag is static. But not when it is loaded dynamically

Comment: when the .restro_book_div is generated via ajax then its not working.